# Find variants that are called in 20% of the samples

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics

I want do this work in R or Linux:

I have a matrix in text format. In this table the rows are contain SNP and columns are contain samples and between these there are genotypes and unmeasured data (A/A,C/T,0/0).

I want to find variants that are called in 20% of the samples (that is: finding genotypes that observed in 20% of samples in each rows (for each SNP) except 0/0).

```
              A         B         C         D
1:14773      0/0       0/0       0/0       0/0
1:14907      A/G       A/G       A/A       A/C
1:14930      A/G       A/T       A/G       A/G
1:14933      G/A       0/0       0/0       G/A
1:14948      0/0       0/0       0/0       0/0
```

Comment: Why not use an established variant calling pipeline? I don’t know much about the field but there are tools for this kind of task.

Comment: Use the right tool, for example: [plink](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2)

Comment: Can you add expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#dummy data
df <- read.table(text="              A         B         C         D
1:14773      0/0       0/0       0/0       0/0
1:14907      A/G       A/G       A/A       A/C
1:14930      A/G       A/T       A/G       A/G
1:14933      G/A       0/0       0/0       G/A
1:14948      0/0       0/0       0/0       0/0")

#get SNPs with at least 20% call
rownames(df)[rowSums(df != "0/0")/ncol(df) > 0.2]
# output
# [1] "1:14907" "1:14930" "1:14933"

#get frequency for each genotype
sapply(unique(c(t(df))), function(i){
  rowSums(df == i) / ncol(df)
  })

# output
#         0/0  A/G  A/A  A/C  A/T G/A
# 1:14773 1.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0
# 1:14907 0.0 0.50 0.25 0.25 0.00 0.0
# 1:14930 0.0 0.75 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.0
# 1:14933 0.5 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.5
# 1:14948 1.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0
```

Comment: It’s not that simple. OP is asking about a SNP being called at 20% with the same genotype. Your code is calling *any* SNP as long as it’s measured. For instance, your code would call a SNP on the following data: `G/A`, `G/G`, `G/C`, `G/T`. However, these are all different variants.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is important for me that in each SNP which genotypes are more frequent

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How can I calculate MAF(minor allele frequency for each row "except 0/0 ;that is not consider 0/0") and after that select rows with MAF>20%?

Comment: @soheil Update your post with expected output.